# Ограничение по времени mysq

Tags: mysql

Есть База с датой которую я использую для работы в С#. Как можно ограничить просмотр по времени минус 5 дней от текущей даты?

Comment: добавить условие `where`  на эту вашу дату. либо создать представление, учитывающее это условие, и работать с ним.

Comment: Тут дело в том что сначала я вывожу текущую дату а потом с помощью переключения даты в календаре переключаю даты. Мне нужно что бы сначала выводились данные с текущей даты. И стояло ограничение на минимум переключение даты на - 5 дней,а дальше записи не выводились. Думаю где лучше сделать в С# или в mysql

Comment: Ограничение на переключение надо делать в интерфейсе. Ограничение на возвращаемые данные - в MySQL.

Comment: Что то не совсем не догоняю ,можно пример